# form validation message (dynamic)

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Is there a way to dynamically tell which `.input` has yet to be entered? In the code below you can see that if I enter out of order, the `#message`
 only counts how many inputs have been populated and displays the message listed in order under `numValid == 1, 2, 3, etc`.

Can the code be changed to dynamically display a message for the `.inputs` that have not been populated?

*****Example: if I type in the `Last Name` and `Student ID` field, the message will either tell me to enter in the `First Name` or `City` field, etc. until they are all populated and the last validation (success message) is displayed*****

```js
$("#form input").keyup(function() {
  var numValid = 0;
  $("#form input[required]").each(function() {
    if (this.validity.valid) {
      numValid++;
    }
  });

  var progress = $("#progress"),
    progressMessage = $("#message");

  if (numValid == 1) {
    progress.attr("value", "25");
    progressMessage.text("Please Enter the First Name.");
  }
  if (numValid == 2) {
    progress.attr("value", "50");
    progressMessage.text("Please Enter the Last Name.");
  }
  if (numValid == 3) {
    progress.attr("value", "75");
    progressMessage.text("Please Enter a City.");
  }
  if (numValid == 4) {
    progress.attr("value", "100");
    progressMessage.text("You're done, post!");
  }
});
```

```css
#mainformdiv {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#form {
  padding: 20px;
}

#progress {
  width: 460px;
  height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mainformdiv">
  <form id="form">
    <div id="progressdiv">
      <progress max="100" value="0" id="progress"></progress>
      <div id="message">Progress Message...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="input">
      <label for="userid">Student ID</label><br>
      <input id="userid" required="required" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="input">
      <label for="firstname">First Name</label><br>
      <input id="firstname" required="required" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="input">
      <label for="lastname">Last Name</label><br>
      <input id="lastname" required="required" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="input">
      <label for="city">City</label><br>
      <input id="city" required="required" type="text"></br>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy to accomplish, just iterate over all of the required fields, and join their ids into a string. If you want to display a nicer looking name, then just map the IDs to an object first.

```js
$("#form input").keyup(function() {
  var numValid = 0;
  $("#form input[required]").each(function() {
    if (this.validity.valid) {
      numValid++;
    }
  });
  
  var progress = $("#progress"),
    progressMessage = $("#message");

const invalidInputs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#form input[required]'))
  .filter(input => !input.validity.valid)
  .map(input => input.id);
  
  progress.attr("value", numValid * 25);
  if (numValid == 4) {
    progressMessage.text("You're done, post!");
  } else {
    progressMessage.text('Please fill out the following fields: ' + invalidInputs.join(', '));
  }
});
```

```css
#mainformdiv {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#form {
  padding: 20px;
}

#progress {
  width: 460px;
  height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mainformdiv">
  <form id="form">
    <div id="progressdiv">
      <progress max="100" value="0" id="progress"></progress>
      <div id="message">Progress Message...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="input">
      <label for="userid">Student ID</label><br>
      <input id="userid" required="required" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="input">
      <label for="firstname">First Name</label><br>
      <input id="firstname" required="required" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="input">
      <label for="lastname">Last Name</label><br>
      <input id="lastname" required="required" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="input">
      <label for="city">City</label><br>
      <input id="city" required="required" type="text"></br>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: `Array.from` is not support IE. Maybe you need add Polyfill for this function.

Comment: Yes but the tricky part is, how do you only display one message at a time? The array consists of the remaining inputs and the order each string appears is numbered so that data-order="1" appears before data-order="2" if the two are both remaining.

Comment: If you want that, then instead of `invalidInputs.join(', ')`, just access the first element in the array: `invalidInputs[0]`. I don't see anything about data-order anywhere in your question